# Can't disable Language bar in Toolbars from Taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar

On all Windows versions, when I disable the "Language bar" by right clicking on the taskbar and unchecking "Language bar" under Toolbars I find that a short while later it is checked again.

How do I disable this permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the Control Panel language settings. There are options to show the language bar under certain scenarios; disable the language bar there and it should banish, never to return. (It took me forever to find this in the past, too.)

This [blog post from Paul Stubbs](http://blogs.msdn.com/pstubbs/archive/2005/02/22/378195.aspx) describes behavior much like what you are experiencing, and links to this [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306993&sd=tech) with the nitty gritty details.

Comment: screenshots for an assist: http://datente.com/images/su39228-1.png & http://datente.com/images/su39228-2.png

Answer (score 2):

Instead of right clicking on the task bar and unchecking the language bar, right click on the language bar itself. From there, select preferences, and unselect "display language bar".

Answer (score 1):

Unregistering the DLL worked for me when disabling it via control panel keyboard and language settings didn't.

Open a command prompt and type `Regsvr32.exe /u msutb.dll`

Comment: I've never seen disabling via Control Panel fail before ... I could be wrong, but I get the feeling OP hasn't found the setting in the control panel yet. (It is hard to find, IMHO!)

Comment: It very well could have been an external force re-enabling it for me after I disabled it from the control panel, but the control panel definitely didn't do it in my case.  Unregistering the dll did it.

Comment: That's wild. I'd still recommend starting with the Control Panel, and only going nuclear if needed. :)

Comment: Yeah, I do concur.  Nice to have a full arsenal when you need it though :)

Answer (score 1):

in

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons\System Icons

you can turn off the input indicator[image]

Comment: That works on Windows 10 too! Even hiding the the language bar from "old" (win 7) settings, did not work.