# Disable language bar - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, language-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t disable Language bar in Toolbars from Taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/39228/cant-disable-language-bar-in-toolbars-from-taskbar)

Ok, so I have googled this and everywhere I see the same answer wich I do NOT need.
What I want is to turn off the language bar ***without*** doing this:

ControlPanel>Language,Region,Clock > Language > Advanced Config and "enabling" click on the use the language bar > options > click on hidden.

I don't see this as a good option to hide this. (Enabling something to 'disable' it).

So my question is, is there any way to hide the language bar without doing the above?

Comment: What's wrong with doing the above?

Comment: I dont see as an option to enable something to just hide it (its just wrong). I'm pretty sure there should be an option to do so perhaps in registry or something.

Comment: @techie007 does that work for W8?

Comment: You should just be able to "close" it.

Comment: I don't see why you consider it a duplicate @techie007 since the solution provided there is for Windows XP and as it the language bar on Windows XP could be literally closed. Moverover thats not my issue.

Comment: The other question speaks of "All Versions of Windows", so it's the same question.  the answers just (mostly) reflect XP.  IMO, it'd be better to update that question via edits, bounties, and new answers than by making a new Windows-8-only version of this (and many other) question..  but hey it take 5 to close for a reason. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do so is by just deleting all the languages that you do not use.

Head over the languages section and click on the language that you use by default and make it go to top by clicking "Move up" and when its there simply delete the other languages that you do not use by clicking on them and then clicking on the button delete.

Besides that one, there only the one you mentioned.

Comment: whoa thanks a lot.. finally a solution that doesnt lead me to activate anything.

Comment: +!: Assuming you only want one language then this is what I've usually done in the past (in previous versions of Windows. ;) )

Comment: I used to nly hit close language bar on previous versions of windows wich is why I made one specially for Windows 8 since I didnt see an option but to "enable" something wich I didn't want to. But thanks tho :)