# How to disable the Windows 8 language bar

Tags: windows-8, language-bar

I have been googling, but couldn't find a solution for my specific problem.
I have also tried what was described in both [Can't disable Language bar in Toolbars from Taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/39228/cant-disable-language-bar-in-toolbars-from-taskbar) and its so-caled duplicate [Disable language bar - Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/503515/disable-language-bar-windows-8), but to no avail.

Consider this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Currently, I have the language bar showing up, because I have multiple languages. However, according to `Clock, Language, and Region > Language`, I don't.

I have tried adding the language, in order to remove it, but after selecting `English`, the option `United States` is greyed out.
I thought, that by adding another language (like `English (United Kingdoms)`), the language bar would replace `United States` with `United Kingdoms`, but no luck: it added a third language, but did not remove the undesirable one.

I only recently noticed the language bar, when my keyboard started misbehaving while I was typing. That's when I noticed I had (somehow) managed to switch the current language to one that should not have been available.
As an additional note: I am the only one with access to my computer and have not recently added any language.

**So my question is:** Is there a fix to this (I want to hide the language bar), and if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was merely a minor bug in Windows 8.
After booting my computer, the language bar had disappeared.

I can't believe rebooting was the only thing I did *not* try before asking, I'm truly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you click "Language preferences" in that popup, what language(s) does it show? You cannot remove the language at the top of the list, have you tried moving the undesirable language lower in the list and removing it? Also Windows key + space switches languages, maybe you inadvertently pressed that key combination.

Comment: `If you click "Language preferences" in that popup, what language(s) does it show?` It shows the window, as seen on the screenshot. Evidently, there is no way to "move up" or "move down" an item, when it is the only element available. As it happens, the language bar disappeared after I rebooted my PC. I should have tried that before asking here, thus I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only have one language, but two keyboards.

If you click on **options** (on your screenshot) it should show that you have two **Input methods** and you should be able to remove one.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, but unfortunately, it didn't lead anywhere. As it happens, the language bar disappeared after I rebooted my PC. I should have tried that before asking here, thus I apologize for the inconvenience.